# Swagger-annotations for multiple requestMappings on class level in Spring

Tags: java, spring, swagger

I'm using io.swagger.annotations 1.5.6 to annotate my Rest services.

The problem is that we've defined several different options for the requestMapping on class level:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value ={"/api", "/v1/api", "/api/br"})
Public class RestController {...}
```

Looking at the java docs for the @Api annotation it doesn't seem to be possible to use more than one value.

Is there a possibility to define several values to cover all the cases or can someone confirm that this is a feature that is not supported?

Thanks a lot in advance for having a look!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `tags` instead of `value`? `tags` property allows you to set multiple tags for the operations. For example:

```
@Api(tags = {"api","version1_api","br_api"})
```